# Why would capitalization not work in Opera?

Tags: html, opera, css

The following html is working in IE/Firefix/Chrome/Safari but in Opera the first letter is not being capitalized.  An example would be San Diego displayed in the four browsers above, but for some reason in Opera it would be san diego.

```
<span style="text-transform: capitalize;">
   <h4>
      Location:
   </h4>
   &nbsp;       
   <p>
      <%=refLocation.toLowerCase()%>
   </p>
</span>
```

Anyone with an explanation of why, or better yet an idea for a workaround?

*Yes, the style is in a CSS.  I just pulled it in to illustrate.*

Comment: The markup is invalid, as a `span` element cannot contain `h4` or `p` elements. This *could* explain the phenomenon, but apparently there’s something else that is causing it; please post a URL or a full document in which the problem can be observed.

Comment: This site isn't live yet, but I could post a fiddle.  
So would the proper way to do it be to use a <div> instead?
Despite it being invalid, it does work on the other 4, but behaves strangely in Opera (11.6).  I also noticed this morning that in two word locations the second word is capitalized but the first one isnt.

Comment: Yes, `div` would be OK. And please post a fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What eventually solved the problem was pulling it right out of any container.  The span, as mentioned, is not correct.  Even inside a div, the problem persisted.  The only thing that solved the problem was to take it out of the div, and apply inline styles, and it works as expected.  Weird.

Being a JSP, was not able to recreate the problem in a fiddle, and this weirdness is likely due to something in our back-end java implementation.

Answer (score 1):

works perfectly for me: http://jsfiddle.net/Sxt48/ (despite the invalid markup - inline-elements shouldn't contain block-elements).

wich version of opera do you use? does the fiddle work for you?  opera [supports this since version 7](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/text-transform) (wich is about 8 years old). i assume theres something in the rest of your document breaking this, but thats hard to say only seeing such a little snippet.

Comment: I'm using 11.6, and your jsfiddle works fine.  I also tried to apply the style to just that <p> and it yields the same result.  I also noticed that in a two word location it is capitalizing the second word, but not the first.